# what does ((Ord, Ord) -> Bool) -> [String] -> String mean in haskell

Tags: haskell

I changed this question to make it more clear. shortestStringHelper has type (Int -> Int -> Bool) -> [String] -> String. Note the String may appear as [Char] instead depending on how Haskell feels at the time. This function will look a lot like shortestString and shortestString' but it is more general because it takes a function as an argument (Int -> Int -> Bool). Note: Depending on how you write it, you may get (Int -> Int -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [a], which is also ok.
I know how to write the find the shortest string

```
shortestString :: [String] -> String
shortestString  lst = if null lst then "" else foldl (\shortest x -> if length x < length shortest then x else shortest) (head lst) lst

shortestString' :: [String] -> String
shortestString'  lst = if null lst then "" else foldl (\shortest x -> if length x <= length shortest then x else shortest) (head lst) lst
```

and they work, but I am not sure if I understand this question, and I don't know what does `((Ord, Ord) -> Bool)` means.

Comment: A question for a question: what is `Ord`? Presumably it is defined somewhere in your assignment, and you should include its definition here.

Comment: Are you sure it is `Ord` not something like maybe `Ord a => (a,a) -> Bool`?

Comment: Instead of `foldl` one could use `foldr1 (\s1 s2 -> bool s2 s1 (length s1 < length s2))` though.

Comment: Given the updated question, here is a hint. You write `if length x < length shortest then ... else ...`. What type does `(<)` have? Do you recognize that type from anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ord` means something incompatible with that in the `Prelude`, but ordinarily the type signature you give would be a function with two arguments.

The first argument has type `(Ord, Ord) -> Bool`, a function that takes a pair of `Ord` and returns a `Bool`.  In context, this might be intended as a generalized comparison function, such as one that compares the lengths of two strings expressed as whatever an `Ord` is here.  This is unusual, because you would expect something like that to be written like `isShorter :: String -> String -> Bool`, or maybe `isShorter :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool`.

The second argument has type `[String]`, a list of `String` objects.  The function returns a single `String`.

However, you haven’t given us enough information to understand what’s going on in this specific assignment.

**Edit:** You’ve updated your question so that the type of the first argument is `(Int, Int) -> Bool` rather than `(Ord, Ord) -> Bool`, which makes more sense.  This might be a way to wrap a comparison on two arguments, such as the lengths of two strings, for a higher-order function that expects one argument.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for making you confused.

Comment: That makes more sense.  In context, I would guess that you’ve got something that wraps `(length string1, length string2)` and passes it to the helper function as a single argument.